# Actionscript 3; how do I have one movie clip interact(collision) with two instances of another movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new to actionscript and I have this problem.
This is the code I used for collision (and bounds) for one instance, but if I put two of the same instance in, it only detects one of them.  Is there a way to detect multiples of the same instance, or is there another approach?

```
function collision(_x:int, _y:int):Boolean{
var TO_RETURN:Boolean = true;

if (_x < 0 || _x >= stage.stageWidth){
    TO_RETURN = false;
}

if (_y < 0 || _y >= stage.stageHeight){
    TO_RETURN = false;
}

if (_x == wall.x && _y == wall.y)
{
    TO_RETURN = false;
}

return TO_RETURN;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect collision between objects you can do :

```
your_object_01.hitTestObject( your_object_02 )
```

To detect collision with a specific point (position), you can use :

```
your_object.hitTestPoint(ref_point.x, ref_point.y, true)
```

For more details, take a look here : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#methodSummary